# Golang Lambda Function Determine Source

Tags: go, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda function in AWS written in Golang and I have two possible sources of triggering an execution. One is a direct HTTP request to an application load balancer that is transferred to the Lambda function and handled via the `github.com/akrylysov/algnhsa` adapter package, and the other being a scheduled CloudWatch event rule that publishes an event payload to SNS and triggers the function.

Right now, my `main` handler function looks like:

```golang
func main() {
    router := api.NewRouter()
    api.LaunchServerWithAdapter(router)
}
```

As per the documentation, the `github.com/akrylysov/algnhsa` package picks up the context and event payload and converts it from the ALB payload to a raw HTTP request, however, I also want to be able to handle an event from CloudWatch triggering the function.

I can't seem to find a way to manage this from the top-level handler. A lot of example have something similar to:

```golang
func main() {
    lambda.Start(handler)
}

func handler(ctx context.Context, event *MyCustomEventType) {
    // ...
}
```

The problem with this is that I need to determine the source of the execution *prior* to defining the Lambda starting point. Has anyone solve this sort of issue before?

Comment: handler has to be set up before the lambda can run, so I think you need to find a different way.  Or have different lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the handler can receive `interface{}` to support multiple input types

Give something like this a try and let us know if it works, I can't invest the time right now for all the boilerplate required to test it.

```golang
func handler(ctx context.Context, evt interface{}) error {

  switch t := evt.(type) {
      case events.ALBTargetGroupRequest: 
           return doALB(ctx, t)
      case events.APIGatewayProxyRequest:
           return doAPIGateway(ctx, t)
      default:
           fmt.Println("ALWAYS HANDLE THE DEFAULT!!  ")
           return nil
  }
}
```